# How to taste a real ranch dressing outisde of the US

Tags: sauce, salad-dressing

When I have been to the South Carolina, US, I fell in love with the popular american Ranch dressing. As an foreigner, I do not know much about this dressing, its origin and sorts, and never bought it in supermarket, but I really liked this one, which was served in McDonalds:

[image: McDonalds ranch dressing]

After coming back to Almaty, Kazakhstan, I made several attempts to find this sauce in my home city and feel this taste again. However, they all have failed - there are hundreds of sauces and dressings here: from mustard to caesar dressing, from local manufacturers to Heinz, but there is no ranch - I am not sure if it is simply not popular here or it is just perishable. Even McDonalds Kazakhstan doesn't serve the ranch.

I have only found ranch in a store once, in a plastic, but it was really AWFUL. It was something like horseradish with tons of vinegar and mayonnaise. I was really dissapointed. I am not quite sure if it was deteriorated or it should have tasted like this.

I have several possible ways to obtain ranch dressing now: I can order something through the local import store. They offer [this manufacturer (image)](http://images.kz.prom.st/9208577_w640_h640_derevenskij_so___farms340g.jpg). I can order [Hidden Valley ranch dressing (image)](https://5e3688a635c3669d3185-a57754d99522d7ca502d9d99cc515a37.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Dressings-Original-lbox-373x400-FFFFFF.png) from Amazon. However, I don't want to spend money, wait for a month or two, and get disappointed again.

Now, I have several related questions, that would really help me. I strongly believe that you can know the answers, because you live in this country and some of you buy bottled ranch in supermarkets.

So, does McDonalds ranch somehow differ from the bottled, sold in supermarkets? What kind of ranch dressings do taste the same, fresh and tasty? Is there a chance to order ranch from the US from Amazon and receive it until it deteriorates?

I would like to have the most possible information about this lovely thing.

Comment: Hidden Valley started the ranch craze. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranch_dressing) Back in the day you could buy a powdered mix that you added to buttermilk and sour cream. These days an awful lot of sour-cream-thinned-with-milk is sold as ranch dressing. Your best bet is probably to search for a recipe for home-made ranch dressing and then try to source the ingredients locally or by mail order.

Comment: @KateGregory You can still buy the powered mix, AFAIK...

Comment: Hidden Valley won't disappoint you.  Everyone else is a copycat; they're the original.

Comment: Thank you all. I will both order Hidden Valley ranch dressing and try to prepare it myself using the recipe from @Shalryn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [this copycat recipe](http://www.topsecretrecipes.com/Hidden-Valley-The-Original-Ranch-Dressing-Copycat-Recipe.html) to make it at home. Depending on who's coming for dinner, I change up the herbs and the type of vinegar I use, and I usually use half black pepper and half white pepper. Other than that, just use it as is.

Comment: Link goes to a page that charges a fee to 'unlock' the secret recipie.